# Google Api Media upload returns null

Tags: c#, api

```
        private static void Upload(string path, DriveService driveService)
        {
            var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File()
            {
                Title = "photo.jpg",
            };
            FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request;
            using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path,System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                request = driveService.Files.Insert(fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }
            var file = request.ResponseBody;
            Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);

        }
```

I am trying to upload a file to google drive but every it returns null.
New to C#

Comment: I don't know about the port to C#, but the java version has a bit of a different structure. Can you provide the link to the C# documentation. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert